# How to Position a React Native Button at the bottom of my screen to work on multiple ios devices

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am young to react native search the web for tutorials that could help me with this problem but have not find anything. I know how to move the buttons from point A to B on my screen. The thing is I just cant seem to get it to be fixed at the bottom to work on different form factors of my ios emulator. 
So far I have tried marginTop which takes down the button to the screen  but as soon as a I change the emulator to a different screen size the button goes up a little. I am asking can I get any guidance as how I may set this to work on different ios screens.

```
  submitButton: {
    height: 85,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FFBB34",
    borderColor: "#555555",
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    marginTop: 200,
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
}
```

The code above is my button.

Comment: Okay I will answer my own question for many users who want to know well I think my problem was the understanding of flexbox. The case is you need to know how to create rows an column which will hold the buttons like divs I hope this help others in understanding with how to position your buttons for future purpose https://rnplay.org/apps/5N7vJA

Answer (score 50):

You can use absolute position to put things wherever you want...

```
submitButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
}
```

will put at bottom of screen, left side....

Comment: I would advice against this, because React Native works really bad when combining TouchableOpacity with absolute positioning

Comment: @visscher then what do you suggest to use?

Answer (score 23):

Here is how I placed the floating button at the bottom-right of the screen.

```
return (
        <View style={mainConatinerStyle}>
            {this.renderSwiper()}
            {this.renderFloatingMenu()}
        </View>
    );
```

Use the following styles for container & button:

```
mainConatinerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1
},floatingMenuButtonStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 35
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Remove the flex-end to center align it as long as the parent container has align-items: 'center'

Answer (score 12):

You can try the code below at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html until that link doesn't work anymore.

Basically you are splitting the screen into 3 pieces, top scrollable, and bottom.  The code below is just doing 3 views for simplicity (no scrolling, just replace the middle one with a ScrollView to have somethign more useful.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';

export default class JustifyContentBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `justifyContent` to `center`.
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `row`.
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}>
        <View style={{height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: most useful answer,, even if you take of height and replaced it with padding

Answer (score 0):

the element

```js
 <View style={style.viewBtn}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={style.btn} onPress={() => {}}>
    <Text style={style.txtBtn}>Send</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```

the CSS

```css
 viewBtn: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    height: window.height * 0.1,
    width: window.width * 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btn: {
    height: window.height * 0.07,
    width: window.width * 0.8,
    backgroundColor: colors.cornflower,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  txtBtn: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 21,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
```

hope this code help your problem, dont forget to use dimension to set height and weight, but optional to use the dimension